# style="display:none" breaks publish page when saving Error: "Not Allowed"

Tags: error, custom-fields, publish-layout

Having a strange issue where I am inserting google / facebook tracking snippets into a textarea custom field (formatting: none).

In one of the snippets of code an image has style="display:none", if I change to display:inline or anything else, it doesnt break. Only if set to display:none??

```
<img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=XXXXXXXXXX&amp;cd[value]=0.00&amp;cd[currency]=GBP&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>
```

[image: Not Allowed error]

Comment: How odd. Do you get the same result if you use single quotes?  How about if you add a semicolon?

Comment: That looks like a server-generated error, not an EE-generated error. I'd inquire with your host about any `mod_security` or other hardening settings that might be enabled. Sometimes they can be very strict about what kind of data can be sent via `POST`.

Comment: Thanks Derek, I contacted the host and they changed a mod_security rule that was causing this.

Comment: Great to hear Mark, I've added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a server-generated error, not an EE-generated error. I'd inquire with your host about any `mod_security` or other hardening settings that might be enabled. Sometimes they can be very strict about what kind of data can be sent via `POST`.